# Windows 8 ScrollViewer breaks TextBlock Wrap

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, scrollview, windows-8.1

I have a ListView that contains a grid with a few textboxes and the width of the column is bound to the page's ActualWidth property.

The problem is that the vertical scroll bar is placed after the largest item in the list (not snapped to the right side of the page). If I add a ScrollViewer before my ListView the vertical scroll bar is positioned right where I want it to be (snapped to the right side of the page), however the text no longer Wraps (spans on multiple lines to fit all text on the screen) but it keeps going outside of the window's bounds.

This is the xaml that has text wrapping working:

```
<Grid x:Name="detailsGrid" Margin="120,0,10,10" Grid.Row="1">
    <tools:customListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items, ElementName=pageRoot}" SelectionMode="None" IsItemClickEnabled="True" Margin="5,5,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemClick="list_ItemClick">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="270"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderThickness="{Binding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="#cccccc" Margin="{Binding BorderMargin}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=pageRoot}"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Image Width="32" MaxWidth="32" Height="32" MaxHeight="32" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{Binding Margin}" Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Stretch="Fill" Visibility="{Binding ImageVisibility}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="{Binding FontWeight}" Style="{Binding StatusStyle}" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Details}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" Visibility="{Binding DetailsVisibility}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </tools:customListView>
</Grid>
```

Here is the xaml that has the properly aligned scroll bar but text wrapping broken: https://gist.github.com/paulcsiki/10388526

What I have to do so I get the scrollbar on the right hand side of the screen and to have text wrapping working?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `ListView`

```
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
```

Comment: I added them to the ListView and the TextBlocks are still not wrapping while inside the ScrollViewer.

Comment: Can you change the `ActualWidth` to `Width`

Comment: Here is the current code: https://gist.github.com/paulcsiki/10388526/c70929fe5173554d14976482db837a40844be3c5 . The wrapping functionality is still not working. Remember that it works if I remove the scroll viewer.

Comment: I don't have your `CustomListView` and a quick `ViewModel` to bind it with. Can you show me a picture of what it looks like if you remove the `ScrollViewer`